# fpdf not works in ie7

Tags: php, fpdf

i am using fpdf library for displaying pdf to viewers. All browsers displays pdf but i met a problem with ie7. since nothing is displayed.

**sample pdf code i had used to check in ie.**

```
require 'fpdf.php';
class PDF 
{
//Necessary codes for header footer body sction
}

$pdf=new PDF();
$title='Faq in Current Account';
$pdf->SetTitle($title);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Rangan');
$content="This is a sample content";
$pdf->PrintChapter(1,'title',$content);
$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `?q=123` to the url you are calling and change the number every time you call it again when debugging. This prevents your browser and the PDF plugin to cache your request and previous errors.

Answer (score 0):

It took me about 5 seconds to find [this](http://www.fpdf.org/en/FAQ.php#q3) in the FPDF FAQ.